# Internal Server Error: File uploading issue while deploying flask web app

Tags: python-3.x, azure, github, flask

I am deploying a flask web app on azure through github. I am facing issue with file handling.

When I hit the address it opens the first page where I need to upload the file. but when I press submit button to process it, it is giving "Internal Server Error". The .xlsm file is uploading through the frontend using an HTML form and accessed in the api in flask but, I am unable to process(doing any operations or extracting data from it) may be due to the reason that web is not able to access it after it is saving.
I am not sure what path I should give to save my file so that it can be accessed by server.
Mind you that the app is running absolutely fine in my local machine while running it on address 127.0.0.5000 but not after deploying it. I am new to this so doesn't have really good idea how things work. Any leads would be appreciated. Provided is the code, I am trying to run.
Note: I have uploaded the code on a github repo which is connected to azure.

I tried using temp_file_path = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.xlsm') also to store file on a temporary location but nothing works.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/process', methods=\['POST'\])  
def process():  
    if 'file_policy' not in request.files:  
        ("No file part")  
        return render_template('output.html',filename='File not found')  
    else:
        file = request.files\['file_policy'\]  
        app.config\['UPLOAD_FOLDER'\]='.'  
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)  
        path=os.path.join(app.config\['UPLOAD_FOLDER'\], filename)  
        file.save(path)  
        output=(pd.read_excel('path', sheet_name='Input')) #to check if the file is correctly saved  
        print(path)  
        print(output)  
        result=subprocess.run(\['python', 'Motor_Tool_2.py', os.path.join(app.config\['UPLOAD_FOLDER'\], filename), path\], capture_output=True, text=True, cwd=os.getcwd())  
        return render_template('output.html', filename='path')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's anything wrong with the upload. I initially thought there may have been path issue, but I pretty much used the      same code and successfully uploaded a file.

[image]

Since you're receiving a 500 error, it's mostly likely dealing with `output` or your `subprocess.run` method. In order to know for sure, you need to [add some additional logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#log-detailed-errors) inside your `process()` method and observe the logs from the stream.